# Where can I modify my model to fix this error when I make a join with doctrine?

Tags: symfony1, doctrine, symfony-1.4

I am using symfony 1.4 and doctrine, I currently created the structure on the schema.yml for my 2 tables, but when I make the query I get this exception

> SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'o.id' in 'on clause'. Failing Query: "SELECT o.id_aditional_details AS o__id_aditional_details, o.name AS o_*name, o.type AS o*_type, o.group AS o__group FROM ohrm_aditional_details o INNER JOIN ohrm_details_info o2 ON o.id = o2.ohrm_aditional_details_id WHERE (o2.user = 4)"

I have to tables, `details_info` and `aditional_details`, aditional details requires in one of the fields the id of one entry in details_info , I dont know this error because Ive done it with other tables, but this time I have no idea whats going on...

My schema.yml is like this

```
OhrmAditionalDetails:
  connection: doctrine
  tableName: ohrm_aditional_details
  columns:
    id_aditional_details:
      type: integer(11)
      fixed: false
      unsigned: false
      primary: true
      autoincrement: true
    name:
      type: string(100)
      fixed: false
      unsigned: false
      primary: false
      notnull: true
      autoincrement: false
    type:
      type: integer(4)
      fixed: false
      unsigned: false
      primary: false
      notnull: true
      autoincrement: false
    group:
      type: integer(4)
      fixed: false
      unsigned: false
      primary: false
      notnull: true
      autoincrement: false
OhrmDetailsInfo:
  connection: doctrine
  tableName:  ohrm_details_info
  columns:
    id_details_info:
      type: integer(11)
      fixed: false
      unsigned: false
      primary: true
      autoincrement: true
    aditional_info:
      type: integer(11)
      fixed: false
      unsigned: false
      primary: false
      notnull: true
      autoincrement: false
    result:
      type: string(200)
      fixed: false
      unsigned: false
      primary: false
      notnull: false
      autoincrement: false
    user:
      type: integer(11)
      fixed: false
      unsigned: false
      primary: false
      notnull: true
      autoincrement: false
  relations:
    OhrmAditionalDetails:
    local: aditional_info
    foreign: id_aditional_details
    type: one
    HsHrEmployee:
    local: user
    foreign: emp_number
    type: one
```

and my query, quite simple

```
try
{
    $q = Doctrine_Query::create()
        ->select('*')
        ->from('OhrmAditionalDetails D')
        ->innerJoin('D.OhrmDetailsInfo I')
        ->where("I.user = $id");

    $result = $q->execute();
    return $result;
}
catch(Exception $e)
{
    print_r ($e->getMessage());
    return null;
}
```

in the case $id = 4

Any idea? Ive tried

```
php symfony cc
php symfony doctrine:build-model
php symfony orangehrm:publish-assets
php symfony cc
```

but nothing...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's trying to guess the name of the column to join on, e.g. looking for `id` instead of `id_aditional_details`.

It looks like you have defined it properly in your schema.yml, but it's interpreting it as empty because you haven't indented your yaml properly. Try:

```
  relations:
    OhrmAditionalDetails:
      local: aditional_info
      foreign: id_aditional_details
      type: one
    HsHrEmployee:
      local: user
      foreign: emp_number
      type: one
```

Comment: thank you... it was, but the problem was the indent spaces... weird stuffs

Comment: Yes. "it's interpreting it as empty because you haven't indented your yaml properly". Indents are very important YAML. It's easy to miss them :)